# Find number of arguments within each function

Tags: bash

Suppose I'm getting a bash script as argument of my script. The given bash script has a number of functions defined. I'm interested in getting all functions and the number of arguments each  function receives.

I'm having difficulties isolating rows that are belongs to a certain function.

Comment: You want to work with the AST of a bash script? Surely there's a better way to do whatever it is you want to accomplish.

Comment: I can't use AST I can only use pure bash. It is part of a homework.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, unless you assume a certain style of coding. To my knowledge, bash doesn't have any reflection features, so you'd have to write some sort of a parser/tokenizer for bash syntax – or a very weird regex (in case Perl is allowed). Think of a shell script with a number of “forkbomb”-like functions, how would you want to identify them?

Comment: and the number of arguments can be variable, depending for example on the number of files, like `runmyfunc *` - how many arguments receives the function?

Comment: You cannot tell, from the function itself, how many arguments it expects or can work with. Unless the function has a an explicit argument count check in it and even then you can only tell by reading it, there is still no programmatic way.

Comment: Would parsing `env` output after sourcing the script work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I suppose a fairly inefficient but effective way to do it would be to store the $# variable from each function into some global array. The $# variable contains the number of arguments passed to a function. So you can just grab $# within each function and designate a spot for it in some array (or even a hash table so that it's easier to track which function the value came from).